# How to specify FastCGI parameters with Apache mod_proxy_fcgi?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

The PHP-FPM documentation says that it's possible to pass custom php directives from the web server, and [there's an example for Nginx](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#example-78).

Is it possible, and how, to do the same using Apache-2.4 and [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html)?

As an example, I'd like to set a different `open_basedir` for different virtual hosts - all running under the same PHP-FPM pool.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Apache 2.4.26 you can use [ProxyFCGISetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgisetenvif) in the virtual host:

```
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/home/user1:/tmp"
```

Comment: Is here some other way for older Apache versions and one PHP FPM pool, please?